# React unable to find modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

I run into this problem pretty frequently while developing react applications. The latest is hwid. I am using yarn to manage dependencies.

I added the module using

```
yarn add hwid
```

It added it to the package.json file and gave me no errors. When I run the application, it says it is unable to find the module. The module is there in node_modules and everything seems to be correct and in place. So I tried deleting node_modules and running yarn install. I've done this several times. I tried force cleaning the npm cache. I have run yarn remove and yarn add several times.

I am using the WebStorm IDE. It gives me no errors, and in fact, if I let it resolve the import, it finds it just fine. This seems to only happen to me in react projects. I think, but I'm not sure, that it is usually typescript modules that give me problems.

Is there a magic bullet for this? The module is a pretty critical part of my app, so if I can't resolve it using node and react's import system, I'm going to have to just copy the files into my project. I would really rather not do that for obvious reasons.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about typescript modules, have you tries also installing types of that modulea?
E.g.yarn add @types/hwid

Comment: I did, but yarn says the module doesn't exist.